# Documentation on Cocoa application directory layout?

Tags: macos, cocoa, directory-structure, webobjects

I'm a Java EE developer who is used to the following directory layout:

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/code/projectconventions.html

After exposure to WebObjects, and OS X apps in general I see that Cocoa apps use a different layout: Resources, MacOS, Bundles(?), Info.plist etc. and I'd like to compare and contrast the two for a deeper understanding. I can't find any documentation on Cocoa's directory layout. Can anyone recommend any links to read?

Comment: Found it :-): 1) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/AboutLoadableBundles.html 2) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html 3) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_bundle . I hope someone else finds this info useful.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bundle Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good start.